# using Hyperic HQ 4.6 to monitor ActiveMQ 5.5

Tags: activemq-classic, hyperic

Does anyone know if I can use Hyperic HQ 4.6 supports ActiveMQ 5.5? I am trying to establish connection between them. I installed Hyperic HQ agent to a server that has ActiveMQ broker and I enabled useJmx on the broker.

But in Hyperic HQ server I can't find ActiveMQ process to monitor. I can see plenty of other services on that particular machine which I can monitor, but not ActiveMQ. How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** Ok, I found a JIRA ticket https://jira.hyperic.com/browse/HHQ-4380 and I added 5.5 section to configuration file. Now autodiscovery works fine, but I don't see any statistics about queues and topics. I see information about activemq process in general: CPU usage, memory usage etc. Is it possible to add metrics about queues and topics?

**UPDATE 2** Here is an article of how to make visible some ActiveMQ information - http://forums.hyperic.com/jiveforums/thread.jspa?messageID=69458&tstart=0 After uncommenting required lines I started too see infromation about resources: ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.topic/eventsTopic, ActiveMQ.Advisory.Topic, topic/eventsTopic. But there is no my queues in the list. Help!

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you are after needs to be defined within an HQ plugin. [FuseSource](http://fusesource.com) provide a [commercially supported version of HQ](http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-hq/) as part of their subscriptions called Fuse HQ that has ActiveMQ plugins provided out of the box (along with the other products that are part of their offering: Camel, ServiceMix and CXF). With it you can monitor individual queues, topics, connectors as well as whole brokers.